# Displaying a message on button click inside the body of a windows form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox, buttonclick

Can anyone please let me know how can i display message on the body of a windows form in C#.
I need to trigger a message to be displayed on the body of a c# win form on the click of a button.

Comment: And Google didn't help?

Comment: try this.... protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString("MyText", new Font("Tahoma", 8),Brushes.Black,new PointF(1,1));
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }

Answer (score 3):

This how you display a Message using [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598690%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your Message here");
    }
```

Comment: @Saptarsi What do you mean inside the body? Can you show us what you mean?

Comment: I need to display the message inside the body of the form.

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your Message here");
    }

This will open up a popup window displaying a message.

Comment: @Saptarsi i think you are talking about label. put a label on the form, and assign the message to the label content

Answer (score 0):

If you want the message to be displayed on a MessageBox, use the MessageBox.Show() method.
If you want the message to be displayed on the Surface of your form, use Graphics.DrawString() to do the work. For example:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    //way 1
    private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("my text");
    }

    //way 2
    private Bitmap b;

    private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b = new Bitmap(1366; 768);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
        Brush br;
        g.DrawString("my text", new Font("Arial", 12), br, 0, 0);
        g.Dispose();
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void MyForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(b, 0, 0);
    }
}
```